# Tracker.autorun() not running on every update of a ReactiveVar

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-tracker

I have a Meteor `ReactiveVar`, which is used as an update trigger in a data store. However the tracker is not run every time the reactive var is set.

It seems that sometimes when the state is set in quick succession, the tracker doesn't run.

This is the code for my store:

```
const myStore = {
    states = {
        ...
    },

    updateTrigger = new ReactiveVar({ name: null, timeStamp: null }),

    setState({ name, value }) {
        this.states[name] = value;
        console.log('Set State', name);
        this.updateTrigger.set({ name, timeStamp: new Date().getTime() });
    },
};
```

And the tracker:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const updateTrigger = myStore.updateTrigger.get();
    console.log('Tracker', updateTrigger.name);
    if (updateTrigger.name === state-two) myFunction();
});
```

The console logs this:

```
'Set State state-one' // update state-one
'Tracker state-one'
'Set State state-two' // update state-two
'Set State state-one' // update state-one
'Tracker state-one'
'Set State state-three' // update state-three
'Tracker state-three'
'Set State state-one' // update state-one
'Set State state-two' // update state-two
'Set State state-three' // update state-three
'Tracker state-three'
```

I can't see why this is happening.

It seems like a race condition as it's indiscriminate as to which updates it logs and which ones it doesn't.

The states are updated quite frequently (state one once every 1.5s, and then the others every second or so).

Any suggestions as to what it going wrong, or as to other approaches welcome.

I could use a PubSub package. Generally I'm not a big fan of `Tracker` and `ReactiveVar`, but I'm not sure what's best practice here, and I don't want to use `Tracker`+`ReactiveVar` in some places, and PubSub in others.

Having each individual state as a `ReactiveVar` is not as option, as I need to persist the state to a database on update.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what was causing the issue? If not, can you provide a minimal reproduction so that the question has more value to the community? As it stands, it is unsolved and non-reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [Tracker's Flush Cycle](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md#the-flush-cycle).

From the tracker manual:

> ... by default, **all changes to reactive values are batched** up and put into effect all at once, when all JavaScript code has finished executing and the system is idle. ... This process ... is called flushing, and **it's also possible to manually trigger it** by calling `Tracker.flush()`.

Therefore, adding an explicit flush in your code will yield the desired effect:

```js
const myStore = {
    states = {
        ...
    },

    updateTrigger = new ReactiveVar({ name: null, timeStamp: null }),

    setState({ name, value }) {
        this.states[name] = value;
        console.log('Set State', name);
        this.updateTrigger.set({ name, timeStamp: new Date().getTime() });
        Tracker.flush(); // added this
    },
};
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm still having issues. This causes an error stating it cannot flush in a flush cycle. Also sometimes I am updating the Tracker twice in a the same update loop.

Do you know any best practices for using PubSub events in Meteor?

Comment: Then you will need to provide some reproducible sample. You may be running into some race condition. The observer pattern may be a better match for this situation, but let's see a complete example and what you are trying to do. ES6 proxies may also be a viable option.

Comment: Thanks, will look into these things. I think I'd rather use observers here, it feels like I'm trying to hack ReactiveVar and Tracker into doing something it's not really designed to do.